# OrientDb. How to determine the database in the pool or not?

Tags: java, orientdb

I am have some connections and i want identify.
How to determine the database in the pool or not in Java code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's class name will be different from ODatabaseDocumentTx now it should be com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool.DatabaseDocumentTxPolled#DatabaseDocumentTxPolled . But if you need more Java way, publish and issue that is matter of 15 to implement isPooled() method on database interface.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. This is variant of decision.